# Sudoku - How to check for duplicates in rows, columns, sub-squares?

Tags: java

So, I'm trying to make a List which contains the integers 1-9, which is meant to be used for checking the following:

- For each row if it contains duplicates
- For each column if it contains duplicates
- For each 3x3 square inside the 9x9 grid if it contains duplicates

However, I'm not really sure how to go about doing that. Originally my method would check for 1-9, but not for duplicates:

```
public boolean getFrontier(int value)
{
 int n = 1;
    while(n <= 9)
    {
        if(value == n)
            return true;

        else n++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now, I'm trying to use Lists, but it isn't really working...

```
  public boolean getFrontier(int value)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> reserve = new ArrayList<>();
    ListIterator iter = reserve.listIterator();

    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)    
    {
        reserve.add(i);
    }

    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        int n = (int) iter.next();

        if(value == n)
            iter.remove();
        else if(!iter.hasNext() && value != n)
            return false;


    }
    return true;
}
```

If someone could explain how I should go about fixing my code or provide a better way to check for duplicates, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: What do you want to get from your method? A simple `true`/`false` if there are duplicates? The position of the duplicates?

Comment: I just need it to return true/false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JAVANOOB   As far as I understood your requirement, try this

```
public class Sudoku {

Integer values[] = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(values));

public boolean getFrontier(int value) {
    if (list.contains(value)) {
        list.remove(list.indexOf(value));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sudoku su = new Sudoku();
    System.out.println(su.getFrontier(2));
    System.out.println(su.getFrontier(2));

    System.out.println(su.getFrontier(3));
    System.out.println(su.getFrontier(3));

    System.out.println(su.getFrontier(2));
} }
```

it will return true first and then false.

I am expecting there will be separate logic to handle value between 1 - 9.

Comment: Thank you sooo much!! This worked, but idk why I had to the change List<Integer> to ArrayList<Integer>

Comment: Because the Arrays.asList() creates  a List which you can't modify. i.e. it is immutable so add(), remove() will not work.

Answer (score 2):

### The simple way [O(n^2)]

For each index, check if another index has the same value

```
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
    for (int j=i+1; j<list.size(); j++)
        if (list.get(i) == list.get(j))
            // found duplicate
```

### The better way [O(n)]

For each index, save that the number was seen. If a number is seen multiple times, you have a duplicate.

```
boolean[] seen = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}
for (int i : list) {
    if (seen[i])
        // found duplicate
    else {
        seen[i] = true;
    }
}
```

### The delegate way (let some data set do it)

A `Set` is a collection without duplicates.

```
HashSet(list).size() == list.size()
```

### The "hipster" way (streams)

Because the steam API is awesome (Java 8 only):

```
list.stream().distinct().count() == list.size()
```

Comment: Can you expand how I would use Set or HashSet? Currently, I'm using the later by running a while-loop where     if(value == n) reserve.add(value);      if(reserve.contains(value)) return false;  else n++

Answer (score 0):

I updated this answer, because now I think I understood what you want:

- check for each row if it contains duplicates
- check for each columns if it contain duplicates
- check each 3x3 square inside the 9x9 grid if it contains duplicates

---

### Exemplary `SudokuGrid`:

```
public class SudokuGrid {

    private Integer[][] values;

    public SudokuGrid(int size) {
      if (Math.sqrt(size) % 1 != 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid grid size");
      }
      values = new Integer[size][size];
    }

    public void setValue(int row, int col, Integer value) {
      values[col][row] = value;
    }

    public boolean isSolved() {
      int size = values.length;
      int squareSize = (int) Math.sqrt(size);

      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Integer[] row = new Integer[size];
        Integer[] square = new Integer[size];
        Integer[] column = values[i].clone();

        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
          row[j] = values[j][i];
          square[j] = values
                          [(i / squareSize) * squareSize + j / squareSize]
                          [i * squareSize % size + j % squareSize];
        }

        if (!(validate(column) && validate(row) && validate(square))) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      return true;
    }

    private boolean validate(Integer[] check) {
      if (Arrays.asList(check).contains(null)) {
        return false;
      }

      int i = 0;
      Arrays.sort(check);
      for (int number : check) {
        if (number != ++i) { return false; }
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
```

---

Usage:

```
SudokuGrid sudokuGrid = new SudokuGrid(9);
Integer[][] values = {{8, 2, 5, 4, 7, 1, 3, 9, 6},
                      {1, 9, 4, 3, 2, 6, 5, 7, 8},
                      {3, 7, 6, 9, 8, 5, 2, 4, 1},
                      {5, 1, 9, 7, 4, 3, 8, 6, 2},
                      {6, 3, 2, 5, 9, 8, 4, 1, 7},
                      {4, 8, 7, 6, 1, 2, 9, 3, 5},
                      {2, 6, 3, 1, 5, 9, 7, 8, 4},
                      {9, 4, 8, 2, 6, 7, 1, 5, 3},
                      {7, 5, 1, 8, 3, 4, 6, 2, 9}};

for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
    sudokuGrid.setValue(i, j, values[i][j]);
  }
}

System.out.println(sudokuGrid.isSolved());
```

prints: `true`

---

### Important:

Credits & explanation [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46037/126149)!
I just modified the code to a complete class with dynamic grid size.

Comment: Wow, thank you!! Your code is very useful, thank you so much for taking your time to type all that out!!

Answer (score 0):

How about   contains(Object o) method in List ? It will Return true if this list contains the specified element.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.util.Map` will do the right thing for you. The key will be your number from 1 to 9 and the value for example count of times its seen.

Or if you just simply need `true/false` type of answer you can use `java.util.Set` and the time you call `add` method on it, it returns a boolean: true if set did not already contain the specified element.

For your purpose any of this two solutions will be cleaner and faster then using lists.

Comment: I'm trying to use Set, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right Set<Integer> reserve = new HashSet<>();

int n = 1;
while(n <= 9)
{
if(value == n)
reserve.add(value);

else if(!reserve.add(value))
return false;
else n++;
}
return true;

Answer (score 0):

I did not get the question completely but for taking out duplicates you can use HashSet.

```
class Test {
    HashSet hs = new HashSet();
    hs.add(1);
    hs.add(2);
    hs.add(1);
    System.out.println(hs);
}
```

The Output will be like
[1,2]

Comment: How would you check if the value was not added since it is a duplicate? if(!reserve.add(value))?